# Parametrized threshold for LP Approximation in Vertex Cover Problem

Tags: optimization, approximation, linear-programming, parameterized-complexity, vertex-cover

I would like to have a formal description on how parametrizing the threshold in the approximation of vertex cover using LP would impact the approximation factor of the problem.

The linear programming problem would became:

Let $0\leq t\leq 1$ be the threshold (as a parameter)

\begin{align}
&\min \sum_{v \in V} x_v \\
\text{s.t.}\;\; & x_u + x_v \geq 2t &&\text{for every } (u,v) \in E \\
& 0 \leq x_v \leq 1 &&\text{for every } v \in V
\end{align}

And the returned set is $S=\{v:x_v\geq t\}$

When $t=1/2$ this problem would have an approximation with a factor of 2. Initially I thought the factor would always be $1/t$, but if $t=1$ then all nodes would be inserted into the vertex cover.

Comment: Under the unique games conjecture, approximating vertex cover with a better factor than $2$ is NP-complete, so I doubt you can get a better result by choosing a better $t$

Answer (score 2):

Bazzi, Fiorini, Pokutta, and Svensson showed in their paper [No small linear program approximates Vertex Cover within a factor $2-\varepsilon$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.00753.pdf) that every polynomial size LP relaxation of Vertex Cover has integrality gap $2-\varepsilon$, meaning (essentially) that any one-step rounding scheme cannot improve the approximation ratio beyond $2$.

This doesn't preclude the theoretical possibility that an iterative rounding scheme (see the monograph [Iterative methods in combinatorial optimization](https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eravi/book.pdf) by Lau, Ravi and Singh) can be used to obtain an improved approximation, but this is considered unlikely since it is UGC-hard to approximate Vertex Cover within $2 - \varepsilon$, as shown by Khot and Regev in their paper [Vertex Cover might be hard to approximate to within $2-\varepsilon$](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Ekhot/papers/vc_hard.pdf).